# CSS selector conventions: Why does Chrome suggest you to select via #id when possible?

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, google-chrome-devtools

Example: 
I have this element:

```
<div id="foo" class="my-foo"></div>
```

If I click the "+" button in the chrome console [image: chrome_btn]

Chrome will "suggest" to select the div via it's id, and not via class, like this:

```
div#foo{}
```

Isn't kind of incorrect to style elements via their IDs?

Comment: depends on the number of occurences. If you only have the element once and just want to style this specific item with the knowledge of not needing it again, then go for ID, if not, then go class. 
**Unique = ID** ; _Multi = Class_. After all it's up to you, but I refer to this habit as best practice.

Comment: its just a selector *suggestion* heuristic by chrome, nothing to think about I guess :)

Comment: Probably because you gave it both, an id and a class, and since ids have precedence over classes...

Answer (score 2):

When adding a style rule for an element with an ID, the inspector generally assumes you want to style only that element, and not any other `div` elements or elements that happen to match `.my-foo`, hence the suggestion of an ID selector.

It's not clear to me why it prepends a type selector to the ID, though. If it's trying to guard against duplicate IDs, it's certainly not going to prevent the selector from matching two `div`s with the same ID, which is far more likely than two elements of different types having the same ID.

Comment: I worked a lot with this and the rule that I noticed is that Google will pick the most specific selector every time ... for example when there is many classes and 0 ID, google will pick all the classes and append them to the tag to create the selector.

Comment: @Temani Afif: Yes, it generally tries to be super conservative about that. It can't guess *which* of the classes you're interested in styling, so it goes all out. For some reason, though, this only applies to classes and IDs, and not any other attributes. So if you have a `<p align=center data-foo=bar>`, the inspector will add a rule for `p`, ignoring the two attributes (even the data attribute!).